# Hyperledger Composer Rest Server connection with Cloudant

Tags: authentication, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, cloudant

I'm trying to use Cloudant NoSQL DB as a persistent data source for my blockchain identities in my composer rest server. I have the composer-rest server setup in multiuser mode and is using google OAuth for authentication.

I have looked at this question ([Hyperledger Composer Rest Server connection with Cloudant NoSQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406092/hyperledger-composer-rest-server-connection-with-cloudant-nosql-db)) but I'm still experiencing problems.

If I do a composer card list in my terminal I can see the cards in my cloudant database. However, if I do a http get method from my rest server it returns an empty array.

I have the COMPOSER_DATSOURCES variable set to

```
 {"db": {   "name": "db",   "connector": "cloudant",   "username": "83bcdcfc-327b-xxxxxxxxxxxxx4e0ba4a9-bluemix",   "password": "01e6d7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb29adcc85ab35ce9ba",   "database": "wallet" } }
```

In cloudant, I have one database called wallet in which there are a few different documents:

1) a cards document which contains all the business network identities

2) a number of client-data documents - one for each of the cards

When I do /auth/google on my REST server a few authentication documents are added to my wallet database - Is that working as expected? I thought the authentication data was meant to be stored in the browser?

Does anyone know why I can't see my business network cards when I do a http GET wallet method on my composer-rest-server?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: All information regarding authenticated users and their wallets (containing that users business network cards (that include identity) when multiple user mode is enabled) is persisted in a persistent data source (such as that which you've configured).`client-data` is like a working cache (where certificates/keys etc that are retrieved are stored). Your REST client is where authentication occurs (or invoked eg using the access token that's stored locally) and also the REST client is where you would initially have imported the card (using /Wallet/import endpoint) - your /GET call would show this

Comment: See tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest for more examples of using Google Auth